# X Server won't load when I add a 50-synaptics.conf file inside the xorg.conf.d directory

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, input, touchpad

I'm using Fedora 18.
I'm trying to configure my synaptics touchpad, I need the tapping and the horizontal scrolling inside Awesome Window Manager.

I've created a file at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` with the following contents:

```
Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier "touchpad"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "on"
EndSection
```

But when I start the system, it hangs at different points, one that I saw frequently is :

```
Failed to start Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit.
See 'systemctl status plymouth-quit-wait.service' for details.
```

If you want a log file or something just tell me how to get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the first line in `50-synaptics.conf` to

```
Section "InputClass"
```

---

`InputDevice` was used to define rules and options for a specific device and I'm not sure if it's still supported.

`InputClass` is a newer section that allows for matching a number of connected devices depending on various match rules.  Because you have the line `MatchIsTouchpad` you should be using `InputClass`.  This way you're telling xorg to match these rules to all touchpads.  You can see the Fedora [documentation](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Input_device_configuration) for more details.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Could you tell me what's the difference between `InputClass` and `InputDevice`. Also horizontal edge scroll is still not working, is there something wrong with what i've typed above ?

Comment: It might be that touchpad settings for synaptics devices do not work from xorg.conf files.  Does typing `synclient HorizEdgeScroll=1` in a terminal enable horizontal scrolling?

Comment: Alternatively, try adding `Option "SHMConfig" "true"` to the config file inside the `InputClass` section.

Comment: I've figured it out, thanks a lot for your help.